# Rails query help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller:

```
@konkurrencer = Konkurrancer.page(params[:page]).per(15)
```

My view:

```
<% @konkurrencer.find(:all, :order => 'bedom ASC', :limit => 5).each do |vind| %>
<%= link_to(image_tag(vind.banner2, :style => 'border:none; width:125px; height:125px;'), vind.tracking, :target => '_blank')  %>
<%= vind.bedom %>
<% end %>
```

Why does my konkurrancers not sort after the column bedom?

Comment: Could you give an example of daa/What you're expecting/What the output is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to inspect the scope `page` and `per` as the sorting might already be declared in one of those scopes =)